# Fill in missing dates with NAs by group in R - with NA at end of date range as well

Tags: r, date, na

I would like to generate empty rows (NAs) for missing dates in a large dataset. For context, this is a large dataset where each individual (ID) has various years of data.

Here is a simplified version of the data for two individuals:

```
table <- "ID    Date    dist.km
 1 1     2007-10-15     15147
 2 1     2007-10-16     15156
 3 1     2007-10-17     15173
 4 1     2007-10-18     15185
 5 1     2007-10-19     15194
 6 1     2007-10-25     15202
 7 1     2007-10-26     15216
 8 1     2007-10-27     15240
 9 1     2007-10-28     15270
10 1     2007-10-29     15290
11 2     2008-10-15     15147
12 2     2008-10-16     15156
13 2     2008-10-17     15173
14 2     2008-10-18     15185
15 2     2008-10-19     15194
16 2     2008-10-20     15202
17 2     2008-10-21     15216
18 2     2008-10-29     15240
19 2     2008-10-30     15270
20 2     2008-10-31     15290"

#Create a dataframe with the above table
df <- read.table(text=table, header = TRUE)
df
```

I first tried using `complete()`, here:

```
library(tidyverse)

newdat <- complete(df, ID, Date)
newdat
```

The output of this is the original dataset, with NA values for all dates outside of the dataset date range. So, some dates are not filled in. For example, 2007-10-20 to 2007-10-24 did not fill in for ID 1. So essentially it is filling in NA values for dates outside of my date range of distance data, but not within it.

I then tried this format:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

newdat2 <- dat %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  complete(Date = seq.Date(min(Date), max(Date), by = "day"))
newdat2
```

And this worked, but this does not produce dates outside of the date range of each ID. So each format produces the opposite results. I am looking to get at least one NA at the end of each ID's date range to show the end of this set. If this can't be done using `complete()`, maybe my question is: how can I add a blank NA cell for a specific date in every year of my dataset? All datasets start on 10-15 and end on 02-15. So, how can I add one NA cell for 02-16 for each ID in each year?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're close with your second attempt. If you want to manually enforce the limits of the expansion in the `complete` call, you can do it there. It wasn't clear what limits you were after but perhaps the below can get you there. Note that I used two date ranges because it seemed like you wanted to hit two time ranges. But adjust if I misunderstood. Can also be called programmatically if you have those dates stored somewhere. Also, I converted your `date` column to an actual date format using `as.Date()` during import.

```r
library(tidyverse)

table <- "ID    Date    dist.km\n 1 1     2007-10-15     15147\n 2 1     2007-10-16     15156\n 3 1     2007-10-17     15173\n 4 1     2007-10-18     15185\n 5 1     2007-10-19     15194\n 6 1     2007-10-25     15202\n 7 1     2007-10-26     15216\n 8 1     2007-10-27     15240\n 9 1     2007-10-28     15270\n10 1     2007-10-29     15290\n11 2     2008-10-15     15147\n12 2     2008-10-16     15156\n13 2     2008-10-17     15173\n14 2     2008-10-18     15185\n15 2     2008-10-19     15194\n16 2     2008-10-20     15202\n17 2     2008-10-21     15216\n18 2     2008-10-29     15240\n19 2     2008-10-30     15270\n20 2     2008-10-31     15290"

#Create a dataframe with the above table
df <- read.table(text=table, header = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))

# expand by feeding the limits of the date ranges to cover
newdat2 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  complete(Date = c(
    seq.Date(
      from = as.Date("2007-10-15"),
      to = as.Date("2008-02-15"),
      by = "day"
    ),
    seq.Date(
      from = as.Date("2008-10-15"),
      to = as.Date("2009-02-15"),
      by = "day"
    )
  ))

newdat2

#> # A tibble: 496 x 3
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>       ID Date       dist.km
#>    <int> <date>       <int>
#>  1     1 2007-10-15   15147
#>  2     1 2007-10-16   15156
#>  3     1 2007-10-17   15173
#>  4     1 2007-10-18   15185
#>  5     1 2007-10-19   15194
#>  6     1 2007-10-20      NA
#>  7     1 2007-10-21      NA
#>  8     1 2007-10-22      NA
#>  9     1 2007-10-23      NA
#> 10     1 2007-10-24      NA
#> # ... with 486 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you!  I think this will work! And yes, sorry, I converted my dates with as.Date() in R but didn't include that here.